# Function for merged cells not working when referencing cells in different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function (from a colleague who is no longer available..) that takes merged cells and basically writes their value in each and every unmerged cell of a different worksheet:

```
Function MergedValue(rRange As Range)
    If rRange.MergeCells Then
        MergedValue = rRange.MergeArea(1).Value
    Else
        'MergedValue = rRange.Value
         MergedValue = rRange(1, 1).Value
    End If
End Function
```

The function works perfectly when both sheets (the one with the merged cells and the one with the unmerged cells) are in the same workbook.

However since the evaluation sheet (with the unmerged cells) has grown pretty big and is slowing down the workbook I have been trying to move it to a separate workbook.

I move the evaluation sheet (with the unmerged cells) to a new workbook and also copy the function so that it's known in the new workbook.
I simply drag the module to the new workbook in the vba editor.
And copy the following lines from "Thisworkbook" over to the new one:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="MergedValue", Description:="Returns the value of the reference cell in a merged area.", Category:="some category", StatusBar:="some status"
End Sub
```

All this said and done the function does it's job until I close the new workbook and reopen it... then I just get "#Value" errors in all the cells that use the function. It's definitely an issue with the function since references to ordinary cells without going through the function work without an issue.

I suspect it's maybe got to do with Excel writing the whole path into the cells only after it's been saved and closed, but I can't seem to find any kind of fix for this issue!

Here is an example what the formula in the cells looks like after saving and reopening:

```
MergedValue('C:\Users\<myuser>\Desktop\[<name-of-spreadsheet>.xlsm]DYNO_SYS'!N35)
```

Whereas before saving and reopening the path is not yet included and the formula is working:

```
MergedValue([<name-of-spreadsheet>.xlsm]DYNO_SYS!N35)
```

Any idea how I can get it to work on the new workbook?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you re-opening with the source workbook closed? It may be that upon opening your new workbook it is attempting to evaluate the function but has no source document to access.

Comment: Is the source workbook (the one with the merged cells) open or closed? If it's closed, your UDF won't work.

Comment: Either way the function can not be evaluated. It makes no difference if I open the source document first or if I keep it closed...

Comment: You should only see the whole path of the source file in the formula if it is closed, or open in a different Excel instance. In either case your formula won't work. If it's open in the same instance, your formula should work - did you try re-entering it?

Comment: @Rory: You're right. If they are opened in the same instance of Excel the formula does work and the path in the formula disappears.
Is there any way I can make the formula work without the need to open the source document first?

Comment: No, because you can't pass a range object from a closed workbook- you'll only get a value (that's why functions like COUNTIF don't work with closed workbooks). Ordinarily, you could use a Variant instead but your UDF actually need properties of the range besides its values, so it won't work.

Comment: Alright, then that's the way it's going to have to be...
Thanks Rory! If you wanna post your response as an answer I'll accept it so you can get some credit for it! :-)